# Using laragon and Vue, component not rendering

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to upload images using Vue and Laravel. The vue will not render for me. It is probably something small and silly, but does anyone want to take a guess?

`resources/assets/js/app.js`

```
Vue.component('image-upload', require('./components/ImageUpload.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app'
});
```

`resources/assets/js/components/ImageUpload.vue`

```
<template>

    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="image">Image</label>
                <input type="file">

                <div class="help-block">
                    Help
                </div>
        </div>


        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="image_id">
            <img class="image" alt="Current image">

        </div>
    </div>


</template>
```

`resources/views/profile/edit.blade.php`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <image-upload></image-upload>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

from my default.blade.php file. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you dont define div as vue element

add id to div like this and test it:

```
<div id="app" class="form-group">
    <image-upload></image-upload>   
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I had tried that a couple days ago. It does not make a difference either way.

Comment: @DustinSeaward which version of vuejs you use?

Comment: from my package.json file I am using "vue": "^2.1.10" .

Answer (score 0):

Are you running `npm run watch` or `npm run dev` to compile your assets?

If you are not, follow the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/mix).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I am running npm run watch, with no errors.